# Setup Audit Trail: Organization setup action: sRHSimpleRecordHomeEnabledOffOn has changed

Tags: setup, setup-audit-log

I am trying to trouble shoot and roll back a change that was made to our Org relating to a line in the Setup Audit trail but I cannot find what setting it is referring to.

In the Setup Audit Trail it says the action taken was: Organization setup action: sRHSimpleRecordHomeEnabledOffOn has changed.

My best guess is that this relates to record page layouts or the Home screen layout somehow but when I check Record Page Settings all the settings there are the same.

When I search SalesForce's documentation for "sRHSimpleRecordHomeEnabledOffOn", nothing comes up.

Does anyone have any insight to what sRHSimpleRecordHomeEnabledOffOn might refer to?

Comment: It might be related to Standard Lighting Page Layouts as all Objects that were not using custom Lightning Page Layouts we changed around and had related lists moved.

Answer (score 1):

a couple years late but this just happened to us so I've been looking into it today.  There's no documentation on this so I wanted to chime in with what I've found even though I'm a couple years late.

This is the setting referred to by sRHSimpleRecordHomeEnabledOffOn in Setup Audit trail.

[image: Setting]

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that the following pertains to Record Page Settings changes:

sRHSimpleRecordHomeEnabledOffOn
sRHRelatedListViewEnabledOffOn

So if you go to Setup > Type Record Page Settings > Either you choose Full View or Grouped View. You will see the exact stamp in the audit trail.

It shows that user switched the 'Default Lightning Experience Record Page View' from Full View (Beta) to Grouped View and this also concluded the resetting of the standard button. This is an expected behavior and is working as designed.

In addition, it seems that the permissions for making these changes are the following:

> Manage Profiles and Permission Sets
> Customize Application
> View Setup and Configuration

These are based from the articles below:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_profiles_record_types.htm&type=5
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_app_builder_customize_lex_pages.htm&type=5